Is it possible to add additional information to the list of workflow runs in GitHub Actions?
After an action is run in GitHub there is a list of runs shown on the screen, like this.

Is there a way to dynamically add more information to this listing?
I have some information that would be helpful to have that won't be known until the workflow actually partially runs.

GitHub workflow has a property run_name. This doc says:
run_name. The name for workflow runs generated from the workflow. GitHub displays the workflow run name in the list of workflow runs on your repository's "Actions" tab. If run-name is omitted or is only whitespace, then the run name is set to event-specific information for the workflow run. For example, for a workflow triggered by a push or pull_request event, it is set as the commit message or the title of the pull request.
This value can include expressions and can reference the github and inputs contexts.
Unfortunately you can not inject values that are dynamically produced by your workflow into the run_name
On a separate note, you can produce a workflow run summary with custom content that is visible when you click on a workflow run.

So, other than the run_name is there a way to add info to the listing? I assume the answer is no or you would have mentioned it, but I just want to clarify.

There is no other way. This is because the UI will show workflow even before the runner picks it up for execution. You can. often see a workflow waiting for a runner. However, if you trigger your workflow via workflow_dispatch event, you can have more flexibility constructing run-name. To do this you would split your workflow into a preprocessor workflow and the worker workflow. Pre-processor would be triggered by a push or pull request and it would then invoke your worker workflow via a workflow_dispatch event passing in the run-name input. This is quite complex though.
